# php, parse csv, no errors

Tags: php, mysql, csv

you don't really have to read all the code, the problem is probably in the upload file but I'm going to post everything just to be sure, and nothing is complicated about the code, I'm going to post it on Pastebin just to leave this area clean for users to read

- [index.php](http://pastebin.com/rK9z5T2X)
- [upload.php](http://pastebin.com/wjmYHNQf)
- [footer.php](http://pastebin.com/4srHgbTN)

I did `var_dump($_FILES)` and threw some exceptions and

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

no errors whatsoever, in fact it was working like a charm last week, until i decided to update it, nothing gets saved in the database, connection to mysql is successful.

The errors from the console is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showCode is not defined index.php line 158

in an effort to get rid of the error because line 158 is irrelevant, i deleted it, still i get the same error, the same line though line 158 is empty. please note i have made many changes to the script and fixed bugs since have uploaded it,but i will update the index only since thats where the error seems to be. upload.php is still kinda the same but i changed the headers

Comment: Track your browser's Network console and check if you get it.
The least you could provide some code.

Comment: @AtaboyDaniel true that, got it and it's weird, i'll try to fix it though it should never happen, then i'll update my question or answer it - its not my fault so you dont have to read any code from above

Comment: @AtaboyDaniel please read my edit